# Throw new Error doesn't throw and node.js don't complain about nonexistent variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm believe i'm having some problem with node.js, for at least 4 months, but just now i want fix. I already try to re-install, currently i'm using 6.0.0.

My throw new Error('message'); are being ignored by the engine, when i try to do:

```
console.log('test');
throw new Error('error');
console.log('test');
```

I see only:

```
test
test
```

Also, when i try to console.log in nonexistent variables, nothing happens.

What could be?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your code is just getting called twice so you see the first `console.log('test');` get executed twice.  You need to show us more context because what you think is happening is not what is actually happening.  Start by changing the second `console.log('test')` to `console.log('test2');` so you can at least tell the difference between executing one vs. the other and perhaps your function is just getting called twice.  Also, please show us what this code is inside of so we can see proper context.

Comment: And doing `console.log(nonExistent)` will likely throw an exception.  If that exception is inside an async callback, the exception may be silently eaten and not log anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely there is something about the context of your code that is confusing you.   We could help you figure that out if you showed us the context of this code and if you change what the second `console.log('test');` outputs so you could tell the difference between the second log statement executing vs. your code just getting called twice (which is my guess).

And, as a vanilla test of your node installation, I'd suggest that you take this set of code and put it in a file named throw-test.js and run just that file:

```
// throw-test.js

try {
    console.log('test1');
    throw new Error('error');
    console.log('test2');
} catch(e) {
    console.log('log exception');
}
```

You should see this in the console when you run `node throw-test.js`:

```
test1
log exception
```

That's exactly what I see in my running node.js and is what would be expected.

---

Other things that could be confusing the situation:

1. Your code might be getting called twice and that's why you get the output you get.
2. Your code might be inside an async callback that eats exceptions (that's why you don't see any exception logged).
3. You have a `console.log('test')` somewhere else in your code and that's why you see two of them.

---

As for your other comment, the code:

```
console.log(nonExistent);
```

will throw a `ReferenceError` exception.  Whether you see that exception or not in your logs depends upon where this code is.  Again, if it's inside an async callback, the exception may be eaten (depends upon the specific callback).

Comment: Hm, yeap, the problem is happening because of async code! interesting, why async code eats exceptions??

Comment: @Joao - It depends upon the async code.  Not all async code does.  Was your code getting called twice?  Is that why you saw it logged twice?

Comment: Yeap, my code is called from 1 to 1000 times, really depends on how much times i ask by passing as command line option (--times [NUMBER])